# undefined array being returned by Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm using Node.js for this, and here's the code:

```js
const { exec } = require('child-process-promise');

const app = new App();

const isLine = (line) => {
    line = line.split(' ');
    return !Number.isNaN(Date.parse(line[0]));
};
const formatLine = (line) => {
    line = line.split(' ');
    return [line[0], line[1], line.splice(2).join(' ')];
};
const readLog = app => app.client.getMainProcessLogs()
    .then(logs => logs.filter(isLine).map(formatLine));

const printLogs = (logs) => {
    logs.forEach((log) => {
        console.log('\t\x1b[33m%s \x1b[34m%s\x1b[0m', log[0], log[1], log[2]);
    });
}

exec('xdotool key XF86AudioPlay')
.then(() => readLog(app))
.then((log) => {
    assert.equal(log[0][2], 'Media key pressed: \'Play\'');
    printLogs(log);
});
```

Here's some context, once `exec` is executed, I'm trying to run `readLog` which will attempt to read the logs from the output, returning a two-dimensional array (after filtering and formatting), which will be used to assert it's validity and prints the logs.

The problem is that sometimes, I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined` which, in my understanding, means there's a race condition happening somewhere. The error is thrown on the `assert` statement. Again, this comes on goes, so it's hard to reproduce.

What am I doing wrong? I've read [We have a problem with promises by Nolan Lawson](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) and I feel that I've followed all advice there. Returning inside every `then`, always a `Promise` or a synchronous value (the array of filtered and formatted logs).

Comment: That error means that `log[0]` is sometimes `undefined`.  You need to insert a `console.log(log)` to see what exactly it is in the error case and that will likely show you clue.  Probably you need to verify the output before blindly accessing `log[0]`.

Comment: so much unknown ... what does `execPromise` return, what do `isLine` and `formatLine` do and return? why do you `return printLogs...` when `printLogs` return nothing anyway

Comment: `app` is defined earlier in the code. `app` is not returned by any of the `then` statements.
I already said what `execPromise`, check `child-process-promise` module for the details.
`isLine` is a simple `if` statement that returns true, following what is needed for the `filter` function of arrays. The same goes `formatLine`, just a simple not important function. I can edit the code to show those details for the perfectionists, but that's not what people should be focusing on.

Comment: @smashed-potatoes that's bad coding, everybody should avoid [nesting `then`](https://github.com/xjamundx/eslint-plugin-promise). `readLog` returns a promise with a value, so returning `reaLog` to later be used in a `then` is much better